# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.strongswan.android.logic.CharonVpnService.initializeCharon

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am trying to class native methods in my Java class, but am getting error
Anyone can help me please,below is log error message

## **Log**

```
01-09 16:15:48.154 8677-9092/org.strongswan.android D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0058
01-09 16:15:48.154 8677-9092/org.strongswan.android W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 8805 (AF_INET6) in Landroid/system/OsConstants;
01-09 16:15:48.154 8677-9092/org.strongswan.android D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0090
01-09 16:15:48.154 8677-9092/org.strongswan.android W/dalvikvm: No implementation found for native Lorg/strongswan/android/logic/CharonVpnService;.initializeCharon:(Lorg/strongswan/android/logic/CharonVpnService$BuilderAdapter;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Z
01-09 16:15:48.154 8677-9092/org.strongswan.android W/dalvikvm: threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419ced58)
01-09 16:15:48.154 8677-9092/org.strongswan.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-505
                                                                      Process: org.strongswan.android, PID: 8677
                                                                      java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.strongswan.android.logic.CharonVpnService.initializeCharon:(Lorg/strongswan/android/logic/CharonVpnService$BuilderAdapter;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Z
                                                                          at org.strongswan.android.logic.CharonVpnService.initializeCharon(Native Method)
                                                                          at org.strongswan.android.logic.CharonVpnService.run(CharonVpnService.java:225)
                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
01-09 16:15:48.164 8677-8677/org.strongswan.android D/android.widget.GridLayout: horizontal constraints: x2-x0>=640, x2-x1<=253, x1-x0<=136 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x2-x1<=253.
```

## build.gradle

## [image]

Answer (score 0):

The message says it is looking for `Lorg/strongswan/android/logic/CharonVpnService;.initializeCharon" (which is a little weird), but cannot find it. It means either the library containing this code is not found, or the method signature is wrong and therefore the function cannot be found. From the details you have supplied, it is hard to say more.